# String split in windows powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, split

Can you please help me to get the desired output, where SIT is the environment and type of file is properties, i need to remove the environment and the extension of the string.

```
#$string="<ENV>.<can have multiple period>.properties
*$string ="SIT.com.local.test.stack.properties"
$b=$string.split('.')
$b[0].Substring(1)*
```

Required output : com.local.test.stack //can have multiple period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$string -replace '^[^.]+\.|\.[^.]+$'
```

This will remove the first 1+ chars other than a dot and then a dot, and the last dot followed with any 1+ non-dot chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HKYzA0/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%5E.%5D%2B%5C.%7C%5C.%5B%5E.%5D%2B%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]+` - 1+ chars other than `.`
- `\.` - a dot
- `|` - or
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]+` - 1+ chars other than `.`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

This should do.

```
$string = "SIT.com.local.test.stack.properties"

# capture anything up to the first period, and in between first and last period
if($string -match '^(.+?)\.(.+)\.properties$') {
    $environment = $Matches[1]
    $properties = $Matches[2]

    # ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use -match to capture your desired output using regex

```
$string ="SIT.com.local.test.stack.properties"
$string -match "^.*?\.(.+)\.[^.]+$"
$Matches.1
```

Comment: Thank you @r007ed and mtnielsen, both answers worked

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) operator also.

```
($string -split "\.",2)[1]
```

**Explanation:**

You split on the literal `.` character with regex `\.`. The `,2` syntax tells PowerShell to return 2 substrings after the split. The `[1]` index selects the second element of the returned array. `[0]` is the first substring (`SIT` in this case).